# Add onTap listener to appBar (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

We need to add onTap listener to appBar. Not an `actions` or `leading` button. We need it for all appBar. 
I tried to use `InkWell`, but it has visual effect, we no need it.
I tried to use `GestureDetector`, but it works only when user tapping on the text in this `GestureDetector`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there are several ways to do this . i think creating a Custom App Bar is a good way

> Example :

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: CustomAppBar(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("hello"),),
    onTap: () {
      print("test");
    },
  ),
  body: Container(),
);
```

To create a Custom App bar you need to implement the `PreferredsizeWidget`

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  final AppBar appBar;

  const CustomAppBar({Key key, this.onTap,this.appBar}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  GestureDetector(onTap: onTap,child: appBar);
  }

  // TODO: implement preferredSize
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => new Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: GestureDetector(
         onTap: (){...do something...}),
      ),
```